# Question about the generative process in latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)?

Tags: latent-dirichlet-alloc

According to the wikipedia article about LDA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation in the "Generative process" section: 
[image]

Isn't this a contradiction?
As you know "~" symbol means "is distributed as" which means ϴi "must" be a vector of "variables", because only the variables can be distributed as. And when the article says "where i ∈ {1,...M}" and M is the number of documents then ϴi will depend on the document i, in other words ϴi will no longer be a vector of variables rather a vector of values like (0.2 from topic1, 0.5 from topic 2, 0.3 from topic5) for that specific document i !!

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta_i = \theta_j, i \neq j$ (there is only one $\theta$ for all documents), we would end up having documents that are similar each other in terms of the topics used in the documents.

"Generative process" here means "true mechanism behind the data". We will never know how the actual data was generated, but we can model the data. By having $\theta_i$ (unique document-topic distribution for each document $i$), we are assuming that each document can have different proportions of topics.

This is intuitive. For example, let's think about newspaper articles. There are a lot of topics: sports, finance, politics, and so on. Since not all topics would appear similarly in each article (=document), we need to assume $\theta_i$ is different across the document when we generate them.

On the other hand, I think it's possible to have $\theta_i = \theta_j, i \neq j$ as a prior. If we know nothing about the data, the prior can be $p(\theta_i = k) = 1/K$ where $K$ is the number of topics and $p(\theta_i = k)$ means the probability of observing $k$th topic in document $i$ (not necessarily be $1/K$, but it is the easiest way to make $\theta_i = \theta_j, i \neq j$).

Once we observe the data $D$, we can update the probability by Bayes rule.
$$ p(\theta_i = k| D) = \frac{p(\theta_i=k, D)}{p(D)} \propto p(D | \theta_i = k) p(\theta_i = k).$$

Comment: I do not think it will work like . As you said you can take instances from θ according to the distribution i.e. if some category is more frequent than the others then "in total" it should occur more (that does not mean that it should be in every document). So my point is when wikipedia said "ϴm is the topic distribution for document m" then it should either say "ϴ" or "ϴm is an instance taken from the topic distribution ϴ for document m"

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "$\theta_m$ is an instance taken from the topic distribution $\theta$"? Since $\theta_m \sim {\rm Dir}(\alpha)$, I am not sure why we use $\theta$ to get $\theta_m$. If the dimension of $\alpha$ is $K$, $\theta_m$ is a $K \times 1$ vector.

Comment: θi∼Dir(α) means θi is a vector containing variables (∼ means is distributed as) but in that context they are taking an instance (concrete vectors with values not variables) from θ to use it for the multinomial which is a contradiction because one time they said θi is a vector of variables in "θi∼Dir(α)" and then they use the same symbol "θi" as a vector of values when they use it with multinomial. Please see the wikipedia article "Multinomial(θi)" how can the parameters of Multinomial be a variable! ?